# mod_mono: Random CompilationException errors

Tags: asp.net, mono, centos, vps, mod-mono

After a server restart I sometimes get random CompilationException errors like this:

```
CompilationException: CS0006: Metadata file `/tmp/apache-temp-aspnet-0/ca373c84/assembly/shadow/10cad1cb/02cb7ade_1201ab15_00000001/ZedGraph.dll' could not be found -> HttpException: Single file build failed
```

and you can't access the application. If I restart the server again then the problem disappears.

The file that triggers the error can be one of my own dll's or a dependency, like mysql.dll for instance.

I am using mono 2.10.2, CentOS release 5.7 (Final), Apache and mod_mono on a Linode VPS.

Any idea of what can be the cause?

**Edit:** Since my troubles started when I moved to Linode and they use XEN, I have found the option --with-xen_opt=yes that looks promissing:
http://mono-project.com/Advanced_Mono_Compile_Options

Comment: When you say randomly, does your application randomly restart, causing this compilation error? Or initial compilation errors when mod_mono starts your application?

Comment: mod_mono autorestarts the application after n requests I think and I also have a cron task that autorestarts apache when it is not responding.

Comment: is it worth you trying a newer mono build? 2.10.8?

Comment: I will as soon as they deploy the packages because I want to keep the official yum install.

Comment: I updated to .net4 from .net2 but I still get the random errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug (race condition?) with the shadow copying and compilation. There have been others found and fixed before... see http://grendello.blogspot.com/2007/08/new-modmono-and-xsp-developments.html

And this is a report of a similar problem in 2006 http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2006-March/030970.html

Rather than rebooting the system, you can try restarting apache. Note, I have found it can help to stop apache and then start, rather than a restart.

You can also enable the mod_mono control panel and restart the application from there. Add this in apache config.

```
<Location /monocp>
  SetHandler mono-ctrl
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1 <YOURIP>
</Location>
```

To automate this process take a look at [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

Comment: thats what I do now, I have created a cron task every minute that checks it is running and if not, then restart apache. The problem is that sometimes only a single part of the web application fails and the rest work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problems where caused by XEN virtualization and mono precompiled binaries. I compiled mono with the option --with-xen_opt=yes but I wasn't able to compile XSP so I couldn't test if that solved it for sure but I moved exactly the same application to a dedicated server and after 2 million requests I didn't experience any error.

**Update**: Check Mahmoud answer

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had the exact same issue on a dedicated server with no virtualization (8 core i7, x86 Ubuntu Server Edition), so I do not believe this to be a Xen-induced issue. For either the OP (SCL) or anyone else with this issue, I have documented my work around in another SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10309582/17027), as well as having filed a bug report with Mono/Xamarin.

It does seem to be a race condition, but not related to virtualization.

Comment: Very interesting. Since I moved to dedicated servers I haven't seen the problem any more, but since you are having them, I am going to change the accepted answer. Thank you for the info.

Comment: Race conditions can be more likely to happen on systems under more load. Since a VPS is sharing resources that could explain why it appears to be a virtualisation problem but that others with dedicated hardware (probably under heavy load) still experience the issue.